# Accessing device via existing device driver

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, device-driver

I'm looking to write an application that will allow me to control music, etc with a remote control. The infrared receiver I have is built into my MacBook Pro which is running Windows.

What I want to know is how can I go about this? Most of the information I can find online is specific to writing Windows device drivers and I'm having trouble finding out how to use drivers that already exist for a device.

Is it absolutely necessary for me to write my own drivers or is there a way to use the drivers provided by Apple?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows you communicate with a driver by first opening it using [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) and subsequently sending commands to it using [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216.aspx). You need documentation for the driver's API though to understand what functionality is available through which control codes and what parameters they expect. Digging up that information is probably the hard part.